# How to get a feel for rigor/form used in mathematics?

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification, notation, proof-writing, induction

I'm an engineer, and while you get introduced to many concepts of mathematics,
but only with a subset of the vocabulary, and none of the rigor and proofs.
So while trying to read a mathematical book, the following exercise is posed:

> Let $p \in \mathbb{P}_k$ with $k ≥ 1$. Assume that $p$ vanishes on the
>   $\mathbb{R}^d$-hyperplane of equation $λ = 0$. Prove that there is
>   $q \in \mathbb{P}_{k-1}$ such that $p = λq$.

I've attempted a prove by induction, but I have no idea if it is correct, and
if it would be accepted by a mathematician as proof. So the question is, how
do I get to the point that I feel comfortable with my rigor and notation, given the state of iqnorance I'm currently in?

---

My attempt at the proof goes like this:
**Base case**: $k = 1$, $λ = \sum_{i=1}^d a_i x_i = 0$,
$p = \sum_{i=1}^d b_i x_i + c$.
For $p$ on $λ$, $p$ has to vanish:
$$p(x_1 = -\frac{1}{a_1} \sum_{i=2}^d a_i x_i) = 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 0 = \sum_{i=2}^d (b_i - \frac{b_1}{a_1} a_i) x_i + c.$$
Because this has to hold for all $x_i$:
$$c = 0,$$
$$b_i = \frac{b_1}{a_1} a_i,$$
which means $p = \frac{b_1}{a_1} \sum_{i=1}^d a_i x_i$.
Inserting this into $p = λq$:
$$\frac{b_1}{a_1} \sum_{i=1}^d a_i x_i = q \sum_{i=1}^d a_i x_i$$
$$\Leftrightarrow q = \frac{b_1}{a_1}.$$
This shows that the base case is true. It exists, and it is of degree zero.

**Inductive step**
A polynomial of degree $(k+1)$ can be written as a product of two polynomials,
one of degree $k$ and the other of degree 1.
$$p_{k+1} = p_k p_1$$
Given the base case, and the induction hypothesis, we can write
$$p_{k+1} = λ q_k λ q_1$$
$$\Rightarrow p_{k+1} = λ q_{k+1}, \text{ with } q_{k+1} = λ q_k q_1$$
$q_{k+1}$ exists, and is of order $k$, since it is a product of polynomials
of degree one [$λ$], $(k-1)$ [$q_k$] and zero [$q_1$].

Q.E.D.

Comment: Your inductive step is invalid. In more than one variable, even over $\mathbb{C}$, there are polynomials which are irreducible, so can't be written as products of polynomials of lower degree. Anyway, you should do what you're doing now: do exercises, and get your solutions critiqued.

Comment: Do you have recommendation for a place where I can get my solutions critiqued?